# Redefinition of constructor with inheritance

Tags: c++

Why in the underlying example keeps the compiler complaining about a redefinition for the B constructor. If i remove the {} it complains they need to be there. How is this done correctly?
I want to implement the constructor of B in the CPP file and not inline.

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A();
        ~A();
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B() : A() {};
        ~B();
};

A::A()
{
    cout << "A construct!";
}

B::B()
{
    cout << "B construct!";
    cout << "B construct!";
    cout << "B construct!";
    cout << "B construct!";
    cout << "B construct!";
    cout << "B construct!";
    cout << "B construct!";
    cout << "B construct!";
    cout << "B construct!";
    cout << "B construct!";
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already defined B constructor in the class definition:

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    B() : A() {};
    ~B();
};
```

So, when you define it again outside of the class definition:

```
B::B()
{
    cout << "B construct!";
```

you get the error; if the correct constructor is the last one, replace your class definition with this one:

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    B();
    ~B();
};
```

If you want to specify the base class constructor in B constructor definition, you can do:

```
B::B()
    : A()
{
    cout << "B construct!";
```

Comment: When changing B() : A() {};      without the  {} it complains it expects the {}

Comment: please, try my code... `B() : A() {};` is a complete constructor definition; you cannot have: `B() : A();`...

Answer (score 1):

Remove `: A() {}`, that's the body of your constructor, not just `{}`. Add the initializer list to the body `B::B()` you have later on.